# Three Surface Integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

Could someone assist with the following three surface integrals?

**Q1** The portion of the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ that lies inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2 =2x$.

**Q2** The portion of the paraboloid $z=1-x^2-y^2$ that lies above the $xy$-plane.

**Q3** The portion of the paraboloid $2z = x^2+y^2$ that is inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2=8$.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post some of your thoughts. Try to visualise the surfaces first, if you have yet to try anything else.

Comment: The first one, I see it as the area above the circle, $r=2\cos \theta$. The second, the area above the circle of radius 1, the third, above the circle $r=\sqrt(8)$. I attempted all three, all three in polar coordinates, and did not get the same answer as the textbook.

Comment: These are correct. Now, what do you need to compute for each surface?

Comment: The standard double surface integral for cartesian coordinates

Comment: I had "length of cross product of partial derivatives" in mind, actually. Also, there is no "double surface integral". You have just a surface integral, which in this case since this is a 2-dimensional object it is a double integral. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $z=f(x,y)$ and the surface area is $$\int\int_A\sqrt{1+f_x^2+f_y^2}dxdy$$ where $A$ is the projection of the surface area on the $xy$-plane.
Use polar coordinates and so $dA=rdrd\theta$

1. $r=0\to r=2\cos\theta,\theta=-\pi/2\to\pi/2$
2. $r=0\to r=1,\theta=0\to2\pi$
3. $r=0\to r=\sqrt8,\theta=0\to2\pi$
   For the first one, $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and so
   $$\int\int_A\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}}dxdy
   \\=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2\cos \theta}\sqrt{2}rdrd\theta
   \\=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}r^2|_0^{2\cos \theta}d\theta$$

[image]

Comment: I had the same second and third limits. For the first, why is theta constrained the way it is?

Comment: Scratch that. I had that too. Could you evaluate them please?

Comment: I will evaluate one of them now

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\color{#f00}{\Huge\tt Q_{1}}}$: With $\vec{r} = x\,\hat{x} + y\,\hat{y} + \root{x^{2} + y^{2}}\,\hat{z}$
\begin{align}
\color{#00f}{\large{\cal A}_{Q_{1}}}&=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\verts{\partiald{\vec{r}}{x}\times\partiald{\vec{r}}{y}}\,
\Theta\pars{2x - x^{2} - y^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\verts{\pars{\hat{x} + {x \over \root{x^{2} + y^{2}}}\hat{z}}\times
\pars{\hat{y} + {y \over \root{x^{2} + y^{2}}}\hat{z}}}\,
\Theta\pars{2x - x^{2} - y^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\verts{\hat{z} - {y\,\hat{y} \over \root{x^{2} + y^{2}}} + {x\,\hat{x} \over \root{x^{2} + y^{2}}}}\,
\Theta\pars{2x - x^{2} - y^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\root{{x^{2} \over x^{2} + y^{2}} + {y^{2} \over x^{2} + y^{2}} + 1}
\Theta\pars{2x - x^{2} - y^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[3mm]&=\root{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\Theta\pars{2x - x^{2} - y^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y
=\root{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd r\,r
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dd\theta\,\Theta\pars{2r\cos\pars{\theta} - r^{2}}
\\[3mm]&=\root{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dd\theta
\int_{0}^{\infty}\Theta\pars{2\cos\pars{\theta} - r}r\,\dd r
=\root{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dd\theta\,\Theta\pars{\cos\pars{\theta}}
\int_{0}^{2\cos\pars{\theta}}r\,\dd r
\\[3mm]&=2\root{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dd\theta\,\Theta\pars{\cos\pars{\theta}}
\cos^{2}\pars{\theta}
=
2\root{2}\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta + \int_{3\pi/2}^{2\pi}\cos^{2}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta}
\\[3mm]&=
2\root{2}\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta + \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{2}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta}
=\color{#00f}{\large\root{2}\pi}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\color{#f00}{\Huge\tt Q_{2}}}$: Similarly, with
>   $\vec{r} = x\,\hat{x} + y\,\hat{y} + \pars{1 - x^{2} - y^{2}}\hat{z}$:
>   $$
> \verts{\partiald{\vec{r}}{x}\times\partiald{\vec{r}}{y}}
> =\verts{\pars{\hat{x} - 2x\,\hat{z}}\times\pars{\hat{y} - 2y\,\hat{z}}}
> =\verts{\hat{z} + 2y\,\hat{y} - 2x\,\hat{x}}
> =\root{4\pars{x^{2} + y^{2}} + 1}
> $$
>   \begin{align}
> \color{#00f}{\large{\cal A}_{Q_{2}}}&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> \root{4\pars{x^{2} + y^{2}} + 1}\Theta\pars{1 - x^{2} - y^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd r\,r\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dd\theta\,\root{4r^{2} + 1}
> \Theta\pars{1 - r^{2}}
> =2\pi\int_{0}^{1}\root{4r^{2} + 1}r\,\dd r
> \\[3mm]&=\pi\int_{0}^{1}\root{4r + 1}\,\dd r
> =\left.{1 \over 6}\,\pars{4r + 1}^{3/2}\right\vert_{0}^{1}
> =\color{#00f}{\large{1 \over 6}\pars{5\root{5} - 1}\pi}
> \end{align}

$\ds{\color{#f00}{\Huge\tt Q_{3}}}$: $\ds{\vec{r} = x\,\hat{x} + y\,\hat{y} + \half\,\pars{x^{2} + y^{2}}\hat{z}}$
$$
\verts{\partiald{\vec{r}}{x}\times\partiald{\vec{r}}{y}}
=\verts{\pars{\hat{x} + x\,\hat{z}}\times\pars{\hat{y} + y\,\hat{z}}}
=\verts{\hat{z} - y\,\hat{y} + x\,\hat{x}} = \root{x^{2} + y^{2} + 1}
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#00f}{\large{\cal A}_{Q_{3}}}&=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\root{x^{2} + y^{2} + 1}
\Theta\pars{8 - x^{2} - y^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y
=2\pi\int_{0}^{2\root{2}}\root{r^{2} + 1}r\,\dd r
\\[3mm]&=\pi\int_{0}^{8}\root{r + 1}\,\dd r
=\pi\left.{2 \over 3}\,\pars{r + 1}^{3/2}\right\vert_{0}^{8}
={2 \over 3}\,\pi\pars{9^{3/2} - 1} =\color{#00f}{\large{52 \over 3}\,\pi}
\end{align}